# Upload document to Sub folder in Doc Library

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to Upload document(with Metadata) to folder inside a doc library using object model.I am able to add metadata but  i couldn't add file to that item

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url)) 
{
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())                  
{
fContents = DataByteArray(fuDocument.PostedFile.ContentLength, fuDocument.FileContent);
SPList docLib = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[this.ListName];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
SPListItemCollection listItems = docLib.GetItems(query);
SPListItem folder = GetFolderInList(docLib, docLib.RootFolder, "Test");
SPListItem item = folder.ListItems.Add(folder.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.File);

  // i don't know how to add the file to list,please help 

    item["Project Number"] = tbprojectNumber.Text;
    item.Update();

 }
 }



private SPListItem GetFolderInList(SPList parentList, SPFolder parentFolder, string folderName)
{
folderName = folderName.ToLower();
string parentFolderUrl = parentFolder == null ? "" : parentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToLower();
//Look in existing folders
foreach (SPListItem f in parentList.Folders)
 {
 if (f.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToLower() == parentFolderUrl + "/" + folderName)
  return f;
 }
 return null;
  }
```

Thanks